# NAS with a cluster of some raspberry pi

Tags: emulation, cluster

Is it possible to make a high performance NAS with a Raspberry Pi cluster (2 to 4 pis)? With high performance I mean able to handle streaming of 2 full HD movies at the same time.

Let's say I have 4 RPis, each with 100 MBit LAN and a 1 TB USB disk attached. I would love to have a "virtual drive" of 2 TB (redundancy and speed)... Is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I really hate to be a ball buster here, but at what point did you associate Raspberry Pis and "high performance NAS." Although it'd be a cool project like [this,](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jq5nrHz9I94) Raspberry Pis just aren't that powerful. They're low cost for fully functioning computer, but they are by no means cheap for their computing power.

I would recommend a device more adequately designed for the purpose you have in mind. A typical consumer NAS wouldn't cost much more than the 4 RPis ($140 + S/H), the HUB you'd need to interface them, and the 4 power supplies (or one bigger power supply) you'd need. In addition, you'd need the 4 x 1 TB drives you mentioned, all with USB enclosures (RPi doesn't have SATA). All these together would run over $450 easily.

Personally I use an [Apple Time Capsule](http://www.apple.com/timecapsule/), as it acts as a wireless NAS, printer server, 4 port ethernet hub and dual-band wireless N router all in one. It's $300 for the 1TB model or $500 for a 3TB model, although you can easily swap out the drive of the $300 model to your own 3TB drive for less than the $200 cost difference that they charge.

If you require a RAID array for data security/safety, something like a [Drobo](http://www.drobo.com) might be worth looking into.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I think you are right. I think it's better to buy a itx mainboard + 2 core prosessor + ram + 4 sata disks. that'll do it much better, and not more expensive. Thanks for your insight!

Comment: I think that may be over the top. A dedicated windows computer brings along downsides such as higher power consumption and security, whilst not offering any extra functionality to contribute to your goal as described in the question

Answer (score 0):

USB 2.0 would be a bottleneck in your case, raspberry connected HDD can hardly achieve 25-30MB/sec throughput, however the same HDD connected using USB 3.0 can give you 2x-3x speed improvement into the 90+MB/sec. Therefore it would be much cheaper and faster with a different dedicated NAS hardware.